# Need to search through a JSON file live

Tags: javascript, jquery

I searched on Google for the past 2 hours and been using all kind of codes, even tried XML php (which turned out to be slow). I still haven't found a solution!

**Here's what I want:**
I need to search through this JSON file https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/generated/search/quick_search.json with jQuery or javascript, whichever is fastest. I want to search for "name" and "symbol" with a string specified by me.

Upon searching, a total of 5 results will be logged into console. When it's logged into console, it must tell me the "name" and "rank" value of the result.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: ` jQuery or javascript` lol :D

Comment: What are you searching for in the JSON? E.g. name?

Comment: How do you want to determine which "5 results" you want?

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196)

Comment: *Which* 5 results?  How are you searching?  There's not enough information here to help you.

Comment: I want to search the "name" and "symbol" with a string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the assumption you are already able to fetch the data (quickSearchResults), a parsing function would look like the following:

```
function findElementInData(dataPoints, nameOrSymbol) {
    return dataPoints.filter(point => point.name == nameOrSymbol || point.symbol === nameOrSymbol)
                     .map(point => {
                         return { name: point.name, rank: point.rank }
                      });
}
var elementsByName = findElementInData(quickSearchResults, 'Bitcoin');
console.log(elementsByName); // [{name: "Bitcoin", rank: 1} ]
var elementsBySymbol = findElementInData(quickSearchResults, 'BTC');
console.log(elementsBySymbol); // [{name: "Bitcoin", rank: 1} ]
```

This will give you all elements matching either the name or the symbol passed for the given array of data.

Update: It appears you do not have access to the data yet.  This is a full example:

```
function findElementInData(dataPoints, nameOrSymbol) {
    return dataPoints.filter(point => point.name === nameOrSymbol || point.symbol === nameOrSymbol)
                .map(point => {
                    return { name: point.name, rank: point.rank }
                });
    }

function getData(dataUrl) {
    return fetch(dataUrl)
    .then(res => res.json())
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    getData('https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/generated/search/quick_search.json')
    .then(dataPoints => {
        console.log(dataPoints);
        let myResultsBTC = findElementInData(dataPoints, 'BTC');
        let myResultsBitcoin = findElementInData(dataPoints, 'Bitcoin');
        let myResultsEtherum = findElementInData(dataPoints, 'Ethereum');
        let myResultsETH = findElementInData(dataPoints, 'ETH');
        console.log(myResultsBTC);       // {name: "Bitcoin", rank: 1}
        console.log(myResultsBitcoin);  // {name: "Bitcoin", rank: 1}
        console.log(myResultsEtherum);  // {name: "Ethereum", rank: 2}
        console.log(myResultsETH);      // {name: "Ethereum", rank: 2}
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: That seems too specific. Can you please make it so if the search string contains the symbol or name?

Comment: If I am understanding correctly:  For any given element in that JSON document, if the name OR symbol property matches your search criteria, it should be returned.  That is how the above operates.  You can call it with either the name of the currency or its symbol.

Comment: The code works. Can you please change it so that the data is loaded on page load, so it doesn't have to load again everytime I search?

Comment: That edit will allow you to search each time without reloading the data.  If you are going to be using this outside of a hobby project, ensure you have permission to use their API.  If this solves your problem, please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: For some reason, it returns the result two times. I removed "|| point.symbol === nameOrSymbol" then it only showed once.

Comment: Hmm, that is odd, edited it with what the output should be for each example search.  There is some more you could do to improve this, but this should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so if you use PHP, here is what I would do:

1. Load the JSON file into a variable using `file_get_contents`, and `json_decode` it.
2. Iterate through the variable using a simple `foreach` loop.
3. Use `strpos` to check if one of the 2 keys contains a value I'm searching for.

You can create another array or object and dump the successfully searched items into it.

This would be lightning fast.